# What is difference between anisotropy and inhomogeinity of this type of composite material?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, material-science

I am studying some types of composite materials having 2 phases - fibers and matrix. I have some questions and confusions. Any help is appreciated.

The composite has fiber along length and I am studying a cross-section of this material. On the cross-section, the material appears as rectangle (matrix) with circles (fibers). When the composite will have random distribution of fibers, can we treat the material as homogeneous (randomly spaced particles) and anisotropic (modulus will be different along different directions)?

When the fiber distribution is not random, say more particles concentrate at a corner, then this would be inhomogeneous and anisotrpic, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Homogeneity and isotropy refer to two different things.

[Homogeneous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/homogeneous) refers to materials/things that have a uniform composition/structure throughout. This means you cannot easily distinguish one point in a material from another.

[Anisotropic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropy) refers to something which appears different in different directions, as opposed to isotropic which is the same in all directions. Is something is isotropic you cannot distinguish between two measurements where you rotate between them.

It is important to be clear with what you are referring to when you talk about homogeneity and isotropy. In your first example while the modulus of the material may be different along or across the fibers and so the material is anisotropic. However, if you only consider the distribution of fibers within a slice then as the distribution is random you could conclude that the distribution of fibers is isotopic. Ideally you should try and associate isotropy/homogeneity to a particular property.